# AG-Grid React - Custom Floating Filter dropdown - not showing in the front of grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-validation

I have implemented the Ag-Grid Custom floating filter in React as a dropdown with values of that particular column like in excel

In this image Floating filter height has been extended to show the expected output as in this image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80BpS.jpg)  but what if the dropdown has more than 20 values. I would like the dropdown to be in front of the grid (overlay to the front) instead of hiding beneath the false values as shown in this image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9TVP.jpg). How could this be done?

This is a Semantic UI React dropdown and modifying z-index is not helping to bring it upfront. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Together with modifying z-index, have you tried setting position absolute at the same time or something like that?